# Option strategy, Black, Scholes and Merton Model and Lognormal distribution

Tags: option-strategies, black-scholes, statistics

The Black, Scholes and Merton option pricing model assumes the stock price changes are lognormally distributed.

Then, How to show graphically

1. How this distribution changes when

1a)an investor or/and trader is long the stock and long the put?

1b)an investor or/and trader is long the stock and short the call?

How to answer this question? I know the stock price changes are distributed lognormally.

Any hint or even correct answer to both these questions will be accepted.

Comment: You probably want [quant.se], but I don't know that site's policy on homework questions

Comment: I don;t see how a trader holding an option and/or the stock changes the distribution of stock prices at all. Maybe you're reading the question wrong? Or it's a trick question?

Comment: **1a) an investor or/and trader is long the stock and long the put?** (1a) is equivalent to a long call.  **1b) an investor or/and trader is long the stock and short the call?** (1b) is equivalent to a short put. If you are asking what the P&L diagrams for these strategies are, they are easily seen by googling for "option strategy graphs".  If not, then what are you after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a distribution of stock prices then the lower limit is 0. However, if the position is the stock plus a (long) put position then the value of the position cannot be less then the strike price on the put. Hence at the strike price, there is a sharp vertical cut off.

When the investor is long the stock and short calls against it, the maximum value of the position is the strike price.

Comment: I agree with your answers to both the questions. But for more clarity , would you give me a graphical pictogram?  I didn't understand meaning of 'sharp vertical cut off at the strike price' in  your answer to first question.

Comment: @DhamnekarWinod If you look at this URL: https://www.optionsmile.com/researches/covered-calls-less-profit-with-less-risk/ you will see on the right hand side a chart of possible values for a covered calls. You will notice that there is a vertical line. That is, the value of the position cannot be more than the strike price.